# Issue delivering email to hotmail inbox?

Tags: php, email, gmail, yahoo, hotmail

i am facing a problem of delivering email to hotmail inbox.
my email is marked as spam and it is delivered to hotmail spam folder.

**My Code**

```
<?php
    $header = "Reply-To: info <info@appleparking.co.uk>\r\n";
    $header .= "Return-Path: info <info@appleparking.co.uk>\r\n";
    $header .= "From: info <info@appleparking.co.uk>\r\n";
    $header .= "Organization: Mobit Solutions\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n";

    if(mail("my_personal_email@hotmail.com", "Test Message", "testing",$header))
        echo "email sent";
    else
        echo "email not sent";

?>
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should probably check the headers to see why it is marked as spam.

Comment: how to check it? kindly guide me.

Comment: Did you try to google how to check headers? If you really can't figure it out I suppose you can open en second question about that, but I suppose checking email headers is not really a programming question? Anyway, you might try http://email.about.com/od/windowslivehotmailtips/qt/How_to_See_Full_Email_Headers_in_Windows_Live_Hotmail.htm and http://www.emailaddressmanager.com/tips/header.html

Comment: I had similar problems. Had to set up SPF, and remove the reply-to header, which was different form my sender email address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not much you can do from your PHP code. However your code seems to be ok.

Double check your SPF records in DNS. You can read more about SPF records [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework).

Also consider using [Domain Keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail)

Comment: yes, both SPF records and domain keys were not available on server, once you create them it goes directly into your inbox :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd use SwiftMailer or PHPMailer and nothing fancy (such as templates) to make sure emails are correctly delivered.

Answer (score 0):

your script working fine for me, here are the results;
[image]
Some times web Host make problems like these, i suggest you to contact your web service provider for this issue. Best of Luck!

Comment: what do you mean by webservice provider?

Comment: and kindly tell me where you have tested it? on shared ip server or dedicated server?

Comment: @UMAR you have google for some thing, anyway webservice provider where your website placed or staged like "godaddy" one of the webservice provider same like your website or script hosted by some webservice provider and you better know that.